# Table with rowspans setting height and width

Tags: html, css, tabular

I have this little problem with my table. I've tried to set my heights and widths, but it won't work. I really don't know what to do!

My table can be seen here [testpage](http://simonhollander.dk/v/cash.shtml).

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Zn9ep/4/

I hope you will help me!

Comment: Are you trying to set the width and height of the entire table? Your current values defined for stamtavle are too small to fit all the cells, so the table is readjusting its width and height.

Comment: I've tried lots of things, but i really want the table to be smaller in height and maybe a little bit in the width. How and what should i do?

Comment: For starters, don't wrap your texts in <p></p> and you will lose all that height.

Comment: That solved the actual question, but what about my textformatting?

Comment: You can format the texts by simply formatting their container. In your case, you can just format the table cells.

Comment: This works! Thx a lot! :) Please come with an answer, so we can get this one closed :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The width and height of a table should be large enough to fit all the cells. If not, the table will adjust itself and ignore the size that you set.

The extra height of your cells comes from the `<p>` tag, since paragraphs are suppose to be isolated pieces of text.

You can still format your texts without wrapping them in `<p>` by simply formatting the text container (i.e. the table cells).